# How to create a .desktop file application launcher on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, kde-plasma, opensuse

I've developed an application in Qt which uses a launch script, `myapp.sh`. I've created a .desktop file which launches this script, and set:

Command: `$PWD/myapp.sh`

Work path: `$PWD`

However, `$PWD` prints my home directory when I launch the .desktop file, resulting in attempting to launch `~/myapp.sh` rather than `~/Development/build-directory/bin/myapp.sh` (that directory being where the .desktop file resides). Why isn't it correctly setting the working directory to where the .desktop file is actually located and how can I get around this *without* having to specify an absolute path in the .desktop file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$PWD` holds the current [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of the shell, which has nothing to do with the location of the .desktop file..  One way you can do this is with:

```
Exec=$(dirname %k)/myapp.sh
```

From [the spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html), `%k` is "The location of the desktop file as either a URI (if for example gotten from the vfolder system) or a local filename or empty if no location is known."  So this is `myapp.sh` in the same directory.

Comment: +1 Thanks, this works. However I do get two tabs in the taskbar if "enable launch feedback" is selected... any idea why?

Comment: It may be showing launch feedback for the `dirname` executable.  I don't know of a work-around right now.

Comment: Simply not showing launch feedback will be an acceptable workaround at this time, I suppose. Thanks for your help though. :)